# script runs at terminal - but not in cron

Tags: cron, script

I'm logged in as user **pi** via SSH and have a wifi checking script **wifi_test_1.sh** in the following directry: `/usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh`

When i enter the command `/usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh` into the terminal, it runs; i can see the "echos", but when i enter this: */1 * * * * /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh into my crontab -e, I can not see it running.

When i do a `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` I see:

> Feb 24 22:35:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[7537]: (pi) CMD
>   (/usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh)

But no echos from the script.

Is the script running in the background, so i cannot see the echos from the script, when logged in as pi at terminal via SSH?

script for completeness:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Which Interface do you want to check/fix
wlan='wlan0'

# perform check 
if ifconfig $wlan | grep -q "inet addr:" ; then

    echo "==============="
    echo "Network is Okay"
    echo "==============="

else

    echo "================================================="
    echo "Network connection down! Attempting reconnection."
    echo "================================================="


    ifdown $wlan
    sleep 10
    ifup --force $wlan
    ifconfig $wlan | grep "inet addr"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: I believe this might answer your question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40623/where-does-the-output-go-from-at-and-cron-jobs

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things I'd do differently and it's a combination of a fuller version of Octopus' comment, a modified version of the answer by rob and my own thing.

By default, CRON's output is send to the Mail Transport Agent or MTA and on Debian the default is `exim4` and you can read the mail messages with `mutt` for example. And with your `crontab` entry it would send both stdout (your `echo` statements) and stderr (errors) to it.

If you don't have and/or don't want an MTA, rob's variant works good too, but you'll miss any errors that would occur (see my next point for that).
You can have both stdout and stderr if you change it to this:
`*/1 * * * *  /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh >> /tmp/cronoutput.log 2>&1`
This will send stderr (fd 2) to stdout (fd 1) and therefor ends up in your custom log file.
Note that `/tmp/` is cleared on reboot and you'd thus lose any files stored there, but in this case that may not be an issue.

The last suggestion I have is to use FULL paths in your commands.
While developing I'd add   `echo "PATH: " $PATH` so that your `$PATH` is send to stdout and that makes it easy to spot errors or wrong assumptions in your code. `ifconfig`, `ifup` and `ifdown` are in `/sbin/` and that was not in the `$PATH` of the 'cron'-user. Adding a `export PATH=/sbin/:$PATH` at the beginning of the script fixed that.
But I actually prefer to just use the full paths in my code and would thus have used `/sbin/ifconfig`, `/sbin/ifup` and `/sbin/ifdown`.

Comment: upvote to help ward off negative energy.

Comment: :-) ... and with that I've now earned the privilege to downvote LOL

Comment: that is karma baby

Answer (score 2):

When working with CRON I always output the result to a dedicated file, such as

```
*/1 * * * *  /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh >> /tmp/cronoutput.log
```

rather than try and setup a mail daemon

Answer (score 2):

#### QUESTION:

> Is the script running in the background, so i cannot see the echos from the script, when logged in as pi at terminal via SSH?

#### N.B.

> Know first that the script **is** running - it's that the absence of the output you expected only makes it **seem like** it's not running.

#### ANSWER:

Running a script from an *interactive shell* (e.g. `bash` is the RPi default) is different than running it from `cron`.

Consider the situation when you run a script from your interactive shell in a terminal. By default the ["standard output" (`stdout`) and "standard error" (`stderr`)](https://linuxhint.com/bash_stdin_stderr_stdout/) generated when you run a command are sent to the [TTY (or PTY) device](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/difference-between-pty-vs-tty-vs-pts-linux/) (e.g. `/dev/pts/0`) in which [your interactive shell is running](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-what-tty-command/). This `stdout`/`stderr` appears in the terminal as the command/program writes it. You see it in your terminal because the interactive shell knows **where** to send it (e.g. `/dev/pts/0`).

Now consider that same script run from `cron`. There is no interactive shell, and the script has no way to know what your `/dev/pts` is - if you even have one!

So what does it do with `stdout` and `stderr`? Answer: They are sent to `/dev/null`... effectively a "black hole".

However, Linux provides a solution! It's called [***redirection***](https://linuxhandbook.com/redirection-linux/) - specifically `output redirection`. You can deploy redirection in your `cron` jobs very easily; following are examples:

```
* * * * * /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh > /home/pi/scriptoutputs.txt 2>&1
```

The `>` is the symbol used to specify redirection to a file with "overwrite"; i.e. each write action overwrites the file's previous contents. To "append" the outputs to the end of the file, use `>>` instead of `>`.

The [`2>&1`](https://www.linuxshelltips.com/redirect-output-in-linux/) is another redirection that effectively combines the `stdout` (`1`) with the `stderr` (`2`) to capture *both* `stderr` and `stdout` in the same file.

To get only the `stdout` to a file:

```
* * * * * /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh > /home/pi/scriptoutputs.txt
```

If you only want `stderr`:

```
* * * * * /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_1.sh 2> /home/pi/scriptoutputs.txt
```

#### What about getting `cron` outputs in email?

If that's what you want - if that's useful for you - then yes, you can do that. You may configure how this works through the `MAILTO` option in your `crontab`:

> `MAILTO=`                     | This sends no email
> `MAILTO=pi`                    | This sends email to local user pi
> `MAILTO=myemailaddr@gmail.com` | Requires a Gmail account & meeting Google's requirements for an "untrusted" source

IMHO, *output-via-email* is not a good option. If it's sent to a local user (e.g. `pi`) you will have to either install a decent email client, or use the clunky default `mail` utility. Sending to a real mail account requires an SMTP server - with all of the attendant hassles. But again, it can be done if this is what you need.