# Cron Job running, but python script not executing on my RPi

Tags: raspbian, python, cron

I'm having a bit of problem with my cron job on my RaspberryPi.

It's a python script requesting json data from a bitcoin exchange, and packing them into a tarball.

When executing the script from CLI it works fine, files are created and the logging module writes to the designated logfile.

My cronjob, however, somehow misses out on that. There's no logs written by my script, and the output i'm dumping to a file only reads `None` (indicating that there isn't anything outputted by my script).

This leads me to believe that the  script isn't executed at all, albeit the cronjob itself does run.

My `crontab` for user `kraken` line looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * *    /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/crawler/bots/btce_bot.py >> /mnt/crawler/bots/bots.log
```

The same command, i.e.
`/usr/bin/python3 /mnt/crawler/bots/btce_bot.py`, executed from CLI gives me a log containing all the expected data (all url's requested and data received successfully, along with a `print()` to console of the api credentials)

I've chmodded my script and all files it requires (it loads urls from seperate `.api` files) to 700.

```
-rwx------ 1 kraken kraken   1934 Dec  7 18:54 apiHandler.py
-rwx------ 1 kraken kraken    202 Dec  7 18:54 Bitstamp.api
-rw-r--r-- 1 kraken kraken 476089 Dec  9 20:16 btce_bot.log
-rwx------ 1 kraken kraken   1983 Dec  9 20:15 btce_bot.py
-rwx------ 1 kraken kraken    411 Dec  7 18:54 CEX.api
-rwx------ 1 kraken kraken   1973 Dec  7 20:17 jsonHandler.py
-rwx------ 1 kraken kraken    231 Dec  7 18:54 Kraken.api
drwxr-xr-x 2 kraken kraken   4096 Dec  7 20:22 __pycache__
```

The directory is `chmod 755`'d.

```
4 drwxr-xr-x 3 kraken kraken 4096 Dec  9 20:16 bots #Scripts in here
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 kraken kraken 4096 Dec  9 20:16 data #Dumps tarballs in here
```

I realize there have been several questions across a multitude of forums on the web; i've tried any solutions I found but to no avail.

Hence, I'm suspecting it may be a raspbian-based issue? Is there something else that might stop my scripts from running?

Comment: what happens if you run /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/crawler/bots/btce_bot.py without appending to the log? Who owns the /mnt/crawler/bots directory and what are the permissions for the directory, script and log file?

Comment: ..I've added the permissions in the question - read/write/execute for all files in the bots folder; the `bots` folder is owned by user `kraken`. `Chmod 755` on those folders. 
Without appending to log yields more of the same - just without the log file.

Comment: Have you tried putting the command in a file and then calling the file?

Comment: Just did - prints `None` as output, so same as running the cronjob. Meaning it's not doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: building on what @Diederik said below does your btce_bot.py have and relative links/URLS such as the file with your access credentials

Comment: The functions of my library look for files by default in './' yes - is this something to avoid?

Comment: As @Diederik pointed out the cwd maybe different for the command line and cron

Comment: To further debug this change relative URLS in your script to absolute URLS (replace ./ with the full path) second you can add some extra logging output to your script such as start, get access token etc.

Comment: Can someone explain me why my answer didn't answer the question?

Comment: It was not a complete answer, How can you fix the problem once identified. However, It did a good job of identifying the likely cause.

Comment: Thanks for your response @SteveRobillard. The fix was too obvious to me, namely fix the $PATH, hence I didn't state it.

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas what is obvious to us is often not to others

Comment: Then asking for clarification on how to fix it would've been far better imo then a straight deletion of my answer (while I was typing a clarification).
That, I find incredibly rude as well as the straight out dismissal without trying by the OP.

Comment: As I had stated below your answer : Echoing $PATH did not reveal new information. My Python is on my Path variable. You didn't elaborate on what to look for, hence my comment. Regardless, the script works now - it was an issue of not using absolute paths, afterall.

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas I did not delete your answer. I converted it to a comment which is what it was. I also, did it to give you and the OP a little space to cool down, as the tone of the conversation was becoming argumentative. I have restored your answer/comment. Please complete the answer with the relevant details.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I've just deleted it as it only caused negative energy; it surely did for me. If ppl are interested why I thought it was a (good) answer, see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39222/19435

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas I agree that is a good answer, but it has the things I mentioned this answer did not, namely how to correct the problem.

Comment: yep, fair point :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the script was being executed afterall; The library I'm using passes relative paths(i.e. `./path/to/file`) by default, which does not sit well with cron jobs, apparently.

I have edited my code to use absolute paths ( i.e. `/full/path/to/file`) and it runs smoothly now.